# USB Serial data sending gibberish

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, usb, pyserial

i am having an issue i cannot seem to resolve. i am using python on the raspberry pi to read from a usb connection on the pi (that is being converted from serial).

i am able to connect to the usb port and start receiving data with the code

```
ser = serial.Serial("myUsbPortID", 9600)
bytes = ser.inWaiting()
print ser.read(bytes)
```

i know that the baudrate is 9600 (hardware manufacturers docs) but for some reason when i try to read the stream of data i get a lot of gibberish in the form of different languages and characters. After i kill the program my screen still replaces my characters with the gibberish data as i type.

i'm sure this isn't the stream of data the hardware is sending. something somewhere is converting things but i have no idea what it may be.

when i boot up the device and it is initializing then i get readable information. but when the device start operating i only get this weird characters

is there a way to convert these characters to the data that it is actually coming in as?

example pic:
[output screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24lTg.jpg)

Comment: Do you send bytes or text? If bytes then just print it in hex and you will see what you want.

Comment: does it work in minicom/hyperterm? is bytesize/stop bit configuration right? can you dump hex? what kind of data do you expect (and what is your device)?

Comment: this looks like a configuration error (baud rate, start/stop bit, flow control,...). use a terminal program and test possible configurations. another very uncommon error is bit ordering error (if the device sends LSB first and the host expects MSB first) however this is really uncommon

Comment: Have you remembered to connect the ground between the two devices? This usually happens when you forget it. When nothing is being transmitted, the computer will just pick up on the noise due to the missing ground, and write out gibberish.

Comment: thank you for all the comments. i don't think it is text. the docs say that they are data frames in the form of a non-unique start of frame character followed by two 16bit numbers. i tried converting to hex by doing "hex(result)" but i got an error saying it can't be converted. 

how can i know if it is connected to ground between the 2 devices? all i've done was connect the serial to serial port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so i was able to solve the issue of the gibberish with this line on python code (for anyone else having this issue).

```
data = ":".join("{:02x}".format(ord(c)) for c in bytes)
```

where bytes is the raw data, i'm  making it ':' delimited.
seems the connection and baud rate was ok. luckily the data was able to convert to hex ok.